# Run Clink in Windows Terminal Preview

Tags: windows, windows-terminal

**Is there any possibility to run [Clink](https://mridgers.github.io/clink/) within [Windows Terminal Preview](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal)?**

---

I tried to add this entry in Settings:

```
        {
            "hidden": false,
            "name": "Clink",
            "fontFace" : "Consolas",
            "fontSize" : 10,
            "commandline": "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\clink\\0.4.9\\clink.bat\" startmenu --profile ~\\clink"
        }
```

but it opens Clink in a new window.

I think `clink.bat` must be somehow modified because it launches Clink with:

```
start "Clink" cmd.exe /s /k ""%~dpnx0" inject %clink_profile_arg%"
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Looking into the `clink.bat` file

Let us look at the [clink.bat](https://github.com/mridgers/clink/blob/master/clink/app/src/loader/clink.bat) file:

```java
:: Copyright (c) 2012 Martin Ridgers
:: License: http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT

@echo off

:: Mimic cmd.exe's behaviour when starting from the start menu.
if /i "%1"=="startmenu" (
    cd /d "%userprofile%"
    shift /1
)

:: Check for the --profile option.
if /i "%1"=="--profile" (
    set clink_profile_arg=--profile "%~2"
    shift /1
    shift /1
)

:: If the .bat is run without any arguments, then start a cmd.exe instance.
if "%1"=="" (
    call :launch
    goto :end
)

:: Pass through to appropriate loader.
if /i "%processor_architecture%"=="x86" (
        "%~dp0\clink_x86.exe" %*
) else if /i "%processor_architecture%"=="amd64" (
    if defined processor_architew6432 (
        "%~dp0\clink_x86.exe" %*
    ) else (
        "%~dp0\clink_x64.exe" %*
    )
)

:end
set clink_profile_arg=
goto :eof

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:launch
start "Clink" cmd.exe /s /k ""%~dpnx0" inject %clink_profile_arg%"
exit /b 0
```

This is quite well commented so we can see the following chronological structure:

1. Move to the `%userprofile%` folder
2. Set the `clink_profile_arg` to the value of `PROFILE_DIR` if the call is in the form `clink.bat --profile PROFILE_DIR`
3. If there are no arguments jump to the `launch` code and then end (by jumping to the end of the file)
4. Select the right `.exe` based on the system's architecture (technically the process architecture that calls this function: [Possible values of %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%](https://superuser.com/questions/305901/possible-values-of-processor-architecture))
5. The `launch` "definition" (technically *labels*)

You have correctly identified that the `launch` labelled code is what can be changed, let us look at it further:

```java
start "Clink" cmd.exe /s /k ""%~dpnx0" inject %clink_profile_arg%"
```

So this runs the `start` command with some arguments, including the string "Clink" and what appears to be a `cmd.exe` with its own command line arguments. `%~dpnx0` being: **d**rive,**p**ath,**n**ame,e**x**tension, **0**th argument (see, [syntax-args](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)), and `%clink_profile_arg%` the variable defined earlier.

Looking at [`start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start) :

> **Starts a separate Command Prompt** window to run a specified program or command.

The **bold** emphasis is my own, but we instantly now can see why you observed the behaviour you described.

We have several options to  consider now.

## Option 1 - New `clink_terminal.bat` based on `clink.bat`

Although we could edit `clink.bat` the better option would be to make a separate file that we use just for the Terminal.

We can simply change `:launch` to:

```java
cmd.exe /s /k ""%~dpnx0" inject %clink_profile_arg%"
```

and then use your `commandline:` with `clink_terminal.bat` instead.

## Option 2 - directly use `clink` with its command line arguments

Hopefully through you have seen that you can effectively replace calling the `.bat` and simply call `clink` directly with its arguments.

Here assuming you are using a x64 machine:

```java
commandline: "cmd.exe /s /k "PATH_TO_CLINK\\clink_x64.exe inject --profile PROFILE_DIR""
```

## Set a GUID !!!

All the profiles in Terminal have a GUID, you can easily generate one yourself.

Open a PowerShell window and run [`new-guid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-guid?view=powershell-7)

```java
PS C:\ANYWHERE> New-Guid

Guid
----
c97d08e9-03fc-491f-bbd7-9a12b9d6e191
```

Comment: I bet this GUID becomes a defacto standard for Windows Terminal clink integration!

Comment: Wasted opportunity to style a not-so-unique-but-very-geeky "GUID" and plug it here 

Answer (score 1):

Based on Adehad's answer, first generate new GUID: Open a PowerShell window and run **New-Guid** command:

```
PS C:\ANYWHERE> New-Guid
Guid
----
ed8f4d54-a8db-4628-ab4f-317cc6469b07
```

Then in Windows Terminal, in Settings, select Open JSON file (the last option at the bottom left menu). It will open file from the path like C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\settings.json . There find "profiles" section, and in "list" add something like this (use your newly generated GUID here):

```
        {
            "commandline": "cmd.exe /s /k \"C:\\my_programs\\clink_0.4.9\\clink_x64.exe inject --profile PROFILE_DIR\"",
            "guid": "{ed8f4d54-a8db-4628-ab4f-317cc6469b07}",
            "hidden": false,
            "name": "clink"
        }
```

Save the file, and if there are errors, Windows Terminal will show you the error message  and location in the settings.json file where error happened. Usually it's related to not properly escaped quotes or slashes. Save changes, restart Windows Terminal, and see in options new item, **clink**.